# Animation causing crash on touch in Cocos2D 3.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, crash

I have setup an animation to my sprite which I want to happen throughout the game. I'm using Sprite Sheets for the animation purpose. The animation code (including the `NSMutableArray` , `CCActionRepeatForever` etc.) is placed in the `init` method and the code works great and the sprite is getting animated.

Now, in my `touchBegan` method, I'm doing some more `runAction` on the sprite (since I want some changes in sprite position when touched).

The Problem is when a touch happens, my animation stops and the `touchBegan` code runs, and when the `touchBegan` block is finished, the animation resumes.

I tried adding the animation code `[plane runAction:repeatingAnimation];` in the `touchBegan` method but the game crashes!

The code of my `touchBegan` method is:

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[plane stopAllActions];

float currentRotation = plane.rotation;

[plane runAction:repeatingAnimation]; //When I add this line, the game crashes. Otherwise, without this line everything works great.

if (currentRotation==10) {
    [plane runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:
                      [CCActionRotateBy actionWithDuration:.1 angle:-30],
                      [CCActionMoveBy actionWithDuration:.1 position:ccp(0,30)],//Game crashes here (checked by breakpoints)
                      [CCActionRotateBy actionWithDuration:.2 angle:30],
                      [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:
                       ^{
                           [self startDownMovement];


                       }],nil]
     ];
}

else {
    [plane runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:
                      [CCActionMoveBy actionWithDuration:.1 position:ccp(0,30)], //Game crashes here (checked by breakpoints)
                      [CCActionRotateTo actionWithDuration:.1 angle:10],
                      [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:
                       ^{
                           [self startDownMovement];


                       }],nil]
     ];

}
}
```

Please help, as I'm at the last stages of my game development.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried adding an exception breakpoint to figure out where exactly it is crashing?

Comment: @AbhineetPrasad Yes. Like I've mentioned in the code above (look at the commented lines) it crashes on `CCActionMoveBy` line.

Comment: repeatingAnimation being nil could be one of the reasons for a crash at the first breakpoint

Comment: if repeatingAnimation is an action it may not be run multiple times, instead recreate it or try [repeatingAnimation copy] assuming v3 has nscopying properly implemented for actions

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Tried what you said. Didn't working :( Thanks for your effort :) Please help